# is there a better way to break up my paragraph into text boxes or a fix to the current solution I'm doing?

Tags: jquery, split

[my current issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwxpP.png)
https://jsfiddle.net/9exp7qwd/2/
My goal is to breakup a paragraph into different sentences with ediblable textarea boxes, each sentence ends with a period so that's when it's suppose to breaking up. I have it seperating the paragraph with zero issues but i can't seem to get the text into the text boxes correctly.

```
    <div type="text" id="testingL"></div>


    $(document).ready(function() {
        var data = "Fixed missing or non-localized text in some dialogs.Fixed occasional crash when navigating to collections in the library. Fixed display of pending gifts in notification menu. "
        
        
            $("#testingL").each(function() {
              $("#testingL").append("<textarea>" + (data) + "</textarea>")
              $(this).html($(this).text().split(".").join(". </textarea> <textarea>"));
            }
            )});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var data = "Fixed missing or non-localized text in some dialogs. Fixed occasional crash when navigating to collections in the library. Fixed display of pending gifts in notification menu. "
    
        let html="";
        data.split(/\. /g).forEach(a=>html+= a==""?"":("<textarea rows=2 style='width:50%;'>"+a+"</textarea></br>"));
    
        $("#testingL").html(html);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div type="text" id="testingL"></div>
```